# Solr: How to get more relevant results

Tags: solr

Well I have schema like this

```
  Id   Desc
  1    I Love India
  2    I love Paris
  3    I love Usa
  4    I love Dominos Outlet
```

Analyses is like this on "Desc" field

```
  1. WhiteSpace Tokenizer
  2. Lowercase
  3. Stop Filter
  4. Ngrams
```

Now what thing is troubling me is the result of this query

```
 Query : "I love Dominos Outlet"
```

Even for this crystal clear query I am getting results like this

```
 Suggestion 1 : I love Dominos Outlet
 Suggestion 2 : I love USA
 Suggestion 3 : I love Paris
 Suggestion 4 : I love India
```

I have to stop suggestions like suggestion2,3,4 for queries like above

Note :

```
  Question Why am I using Ngram ?

  Answer : I want user to get suggestion for every term/char.
```

Any help/Suggestions

Comment: Default query operator in solr is `OR`, so there is no problem you can suggestion 2,3,4. To get more relevant results, you need more document in sold.

Comment: Ok, Thanks , yean right after getting more documents in solr , all irrelevant result will go down

Comment: Dude , Well rightnow i am using API getDocList() function